# How to automate desktop application using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, desktop

What are the different ways to automate desktop applications using selenium?

We tried automating 360tc java application using Leanft
Some of the objects were not getting identified as expected
Hence decided to try with Selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe: you can download it from vl.6.0. This will act as a server and communicate internally via JSON wired protocol as selenium does.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of the [Selenium homepage](https://www.selenium.dev/):

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it!

So, there aren’t any ways to use it to automate desktop applications (with the exception of the browsers it is designed to work with).